# How is React updating his state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a question concerning React and how state must be updated. 
Let's say we have a class Players containing in its state an array of objects called players. We want to update one player in this array. I would have done it this way:

```js
class Players extends Component {

  state = {
      players: []
  }

  updatePlayer = id => {
      const players = this.state.players.map(player => {
        player.updated = player.id === id ? true:false;
        return player
      });
      this.setState({players: players});
  }
}
```

But my coworker just did it this way, and it's also working:

```js
updatePlayer = id => {
    const playerObj = this.state.players.find(item => {
      return item.id === id
    })

    if (playerObj) {
      playerObj.updated = true

      this.setState({ playerObj })
    }
}
```

React's function setState update the players array without telling explicitly to do it. So, I have two questions:

- Is it using a reference from the find function, and using it to update the players arrays ?
- Is one of those ways recommended ?

Thank you all for your explanations !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that second snippet misuses `setState` to trigger an update because it uses `playerObj` dummy property. This could be achieved with `forceUpdate`.

Neither of these ways are correct. Immutable state is promoted in React as a convention. Mutating existing state may result in incorrect behaviour in components that expect a state to be immutable. They mutate existing `player` object, and new `player.update` value will be used everywhere where this object is used, even if this is undesirable.

An idiomatic way to do this is to use immutable objects in state:

```
updatePlayer = id => {
  this.setState(({ players }) => ({
    players: players.map(player => ({
      ...player,
      updated: player.id === id
    }));
  });
}
```

Notice that `setState` is asynchronous, [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) has to be used to avoid possible race conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! So, the main difference between the the first way and yours is the spread operator which creates a new array, am I right ?

Comment: New `players` array and new `player` objects. That's the point. And updater function is important if there's a chance that state updates can be batched like `this.updatePlayer(1); this.updatePlayer(2)`, otherwise immutable state updates won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are not correct, because you are mutating state.
The best way is a create a deep copy of this array ( just clone ) and after that make some changes with this cloned array

You can also use lodash _.cloneDeep();

For example

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: [
      {id: 0, name: 'John'};
    ]
  };
  
  updatePlayer = id => {
    const { players } = this.state;
    const clonePlayers = players.map(a => ({...a}));
    
    const player = clonePlayers.find(playerId => playerId === id);
    
    player.name = 'Jack';
    
    this.setState(() => ({
      players: clonePlayers
    }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>some</div>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yours isn't a deep clone either. That's the same as doing map. The objects are still the same references. You would need to spread the objects instead.

Comment: The first one is not mutating the state, and the OP's question is mainly how the second piece of code is working!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all it's using a reference. All javascript objects are references so whenever you do a find you get a reference to the object, so mutating it will update it.

```
const players = this.state.players.map(player => {
        return { ...player, updated: player.id === id };
});
this.setState({players: players});
```

As for the recommended way, you should stick with yours where you explicitly update the state variable that you care about.

Answer (score 0):

well, basically they are not the same, your coworkers code is working just because he is using an old reference of the object. so, lets take a look:

```
  updatePlayer = id => {
      const players = this.state.players.map(player => {
        player.updated = player.id === id ? true:false;
        return player
      });
      this.setState({players: players});
  }
```

on your function, you are creating a new `array` using your old array, which is the correct way of doing this.

```
updatePlayer = id => {
    const playerObj = this.state.players.find(item => {
      return item.id === id
    })

    if (playerObj) {
      playerObj.updated = true

      this.setState({ playerObj })
    }
}
```

here your friend is editing the reference of the object that he got using `find` and then saving a `playerObj` which is nothing more than the reference of a player from the array that you wanted to edit. after this you should notice that the new state will be something like

```
this.state = {
    players: [p1, p2 ,p3, p4], // each p is a player.
    //notice that playerObj is now a reference to some of the P on the players array
    playerObj: {
        ...playerstuff,
        updated: true
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)